# How can I remove a dynamically created button?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to remove all children of a `StackPanel` except for a `Label`, but I can't get it to 
remove a dynamically created `Button`.

```
<StackPanel Name="myStackPanel">
    <Label Name="myLabel">Label text</Label>
    <TextBlock Name="myTextBlock">TextBlock text</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    Button buttonX= new Button();
    buttonX.Name = "ButtonInstall";
    buttonX.Content = "Click Me";
    buttonX.Width = 150;
    buttonX.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    buttonX.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(buttonX_Click); 
    myStackPanel.Children.Add(buttonX); 
    }

private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(myStackPanel); i++)
        {
        Visual childVisual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(myStackPanel, i);
        string controlName = childVisual.GetValue(Control.NameProperty).ToString();

        if (childVisual.GetType() != typeof(Label))
        {        
            myStackPanel.Children.Remove((UIElement)childVisual);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not iterate through `Children` if you add there? You'd need to do just `for (int i = stackPanel.Children.Count - 1; i > 0; i--) if (!(stackPanel.Children[i] is Label)) stackPanel.Children.RemoveAt(i);`

Comment: This is why we have MVVM and DataTemplates.

Comment: Why not just set Visibility.Collapsed for buttonX on button2.MouseDown Trigger?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I think the issue was as I iterated through children and removed them the count changed. Like Vlad said, if you get the count and iterate backwards it works.

Answer (score 3):

For your example, it's not necessary to use the `VisualTreeHelper`:

```
List<UIElement> delItems=new List<UIElement>();
foreach(UIElement uiElement in myStackPanel.Children){
 if(uiElement is Label) continue;
 delItems.Add(uiElement);
}
foreach(UIElement delItem in delItems){
  myStackPanel.Children.Remove(delItem);
}
```